# on a termux app terminal access where should I put my own runnit service to start on phone reboot?

Tags: termux, services, init.d

I wrote a simple service like this one: http://smarden.org/runit/runscripts.html#apache2

```
$ cat start_node_exporter 
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/sh
termux-wake-lock
. $PREFIX/etc/profile
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/bin/node_exporter --collector.wifi --collector.tcpstat --collector.runit --collector.processes --collector.mountstats
```

I would like it to run on phone reboot

Comment: Explained here very well: https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux:Boot

Comment: I have already tried that, that sshd example did not work on reboot the .termux folder disappeared.

Comment: Did you install Termux Boot app?

Comment: Indeed, the instructions are pretty clear on the page you shared